# Passport Authentication Redirection to absolute URL fails

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

I want to redirect the request to another URL alongwith the code / token received from the logging into the facebook via `passport` in `express` js.

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', function (req, res, next) {
    var authenticator = passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect: "http://localhost:3200/#/home/",
        failureRedirect: '/'
    });
```

The problem is it dont redirect to the url specified alongwith the code in query so i can manage the state in angular app also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put `passport.authenticate` instead of `function (req, res, next)`:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    successRedirect: "http://localhost:3200/#/home/",
    failureRedirect: '/'
}));
```